# Get value from input, result as NaN

Tags: jquery

This is weird, I'm trying to make a simple calculation, but I'm not able to get value from inputs for some reason, and it's working for only specific inputs, not for everyone.

This is the way I'm trying to get value:

```
var Days = parseInt($('#days').val());
var DaysPayment = parseInt($('#days-payment').val());
```

But it's not working, though other inputs is working fine.

You can see this on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jEU4L/

Comment: i think it may be bcoz of ur replace function try this 
`replace(/\r?\n/g, '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the values from those fields *within* the click handler. At the moment you are getting them on load when they are blank, hence the calculation yields `NaN`. Also, you should include the radix on `parseInt` calls. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $execute = $('#execute');
    var $total = $('#total');
    var $totalNDS = $('#total-nds');

    $execute.on('click', function () {
        var payment = parseInt($('#payment').val().replace(/ /g, ""), 10);
        var nds = parseInt($('#nds').val(), 10);
        var days = parseInt($('#days').val(), 10);
        var daysPayment = parseInt($('#days-payment').val(), 10);

        var t1 = payment / 100;
        var t2 = t1 * nds;
        var t3 = payment - t2;
        var t4 = t3 / days;
        var t5 = t4 * daysPayment;    
        $total.val(t5);
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/98VWJ/)

I also changed the variable names to use the usual JS and jQuery conventions (ie. variables containing jQuery objects are prefixed with a `$` and variable names should be camel-cased).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Payment = parseInt($('#payment').val().replace(/ /g,""));

    var Execute = $('#execute');
    var Total = $('#total');
    var TotalNDS = $('#total-nds');

    Execute.on('click',function(){

        var NDS = 0
    var Days = 0
    var DaysPayment= 0
    if($('#nds') > 0)
     NDS = parseInt($('#nds').val());
    if($('#days') > 0)
     Days = parseInt($('#days').val());
    if($('#days-payment') > 0)
     DaysPayment = parseInt($('#days-payment').val());

        console.log(Days+' '+DaysPayment);
        var t1 = Payment/100;
        console.log(t1);        
        var t2 = t1 * NDS;
        console.log(t2);
        var t3 = Payment - t2;
        console.log(t3);
        var t4 = t3 / Days;
        console.log(t4);
        var t5 = t4 * DaysPayment;
        console.log(t5);

        Total.val(t5);


    });

});
```

Because you are not getting the default value in Days or days in month varables so you are getting NaN